# Issues with Three20 TTLauncherView, TTLauncherItems and UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, three20, ttlauncherview, ttlauncheritem

I have a `TTLauncherView` and a `UITabBarController` and I'm noticing that
the tab bar is actually overlapping the `TTLauncherItems` as I add more
to the view. This is one issue that I'd like to resolve.

When I add more items to the view the launcher automatically moves to
the next page if there are too many items, which is correct
functionality. However if I close the application and load the view
again the buttons that were on the second, third and fourth page, etc
are all sitting out of view (past the tab bar controller if that makes
any sense). The funny thing is that as soon as I move any of the
launcher items to a different position ALL of the items that are meant
to be on the second, third and fourth page move there automatically!

Why doesn't it automatically move the launcher items onto the correct
pages when the view first loads? Is this a bug that noone's noticed or
am I missing something?

I do use code to save the items to a database table and then load them
in viewDidLoad but all the code is doing is adding the TTLauncherItems
to an array, which I pass to _launcherView.pages by doing:

```
_launcherView.pages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:array, nil];
```

Then I simply do a:

```
[self.view addSubview:_launcherView];
```

This works fine, but the above behavior is just really bugging me.
Works fine on the Facebook app? I wonder how they did that? hehe ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up fixing this by reinitializing the `launcherView`.